# Where can I find a cube-like coffee roaster in Europe?

Tags: equipment, home-roasting

I am looking for a coffee roaster like shown in the image below. Does anyone know a source where I could buy this one or very similar from EU (Austria)?

[image: Image of roaster.]

*Source: [YouTube: Peaceful Cuisine](https://youtu.be/I7Z5Oh-hl7g?t=94)*

Comment: What are you looking for? The exact make or a manual roasting machine? Similar are available on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.de/manueller-Kaffeer%C3%B6ster-Kaffeebohnen-R%C3%B6stmaschine-Edelstahlwalzen/dp/B087JNYHDN)

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the exact make.